# WPF, C# Visibility = Visible, Opacity = 1 , element not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, events, data-binding

**Question:**

How and why can I set `Opacity = 1` and `Visibility = Visible` on a element and then get `Opacity = 0` and `Visibility = Collapsed` when I run the program?

**Explanation:**

I have a Questionnaire library I wrote. Questions have a `AnswerRequired` dependency prop.

If  `AnswerRequired` is set to false the question fades out (`Visibility=collapsed` , `Opacity = 0`).

In an application I have a `DateQuestion` that uses a `DatePicker`.

```
<wpfQuestionnaire:DateQuestion
  QuestionNumber="15.2"
  AnswerDate="{Binding LastPregnant, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

the date is bound to a property on the viewmodel, `LastPregnant`. When setting `LastPregnant` I also set the property `PregnantThisYear` (using NodaTime).

`AnswerRequired` of The next question is bound to `PregnantThisYear`. When it updates `Question_TargetUpdated` is called and updates a list of `AnswerRequired` states. The questionaire gets notified about this.

```
<wpfQuestionnaire:BinaryQuestion
  QuestionNumber="15.3"
  AnswerRequired="{
    Binding PregnantThisYear,
    NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,
    Mode=TwoWay}"
    TargetUpdated="Question_TargetUpdated"/>
```

All questions are dereived from `QuestionBase` which has the event and handler `AnswerRequiredChanged += OnAnswerRequiredChanged`.

`OnAnswerRequiredChanged` calls `FadeIn` or `FadeOut` accordingly.

`FadeIn` looks like this:

```
public void FadeIn(UIElement element)
 {
         element.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
         var fade = new DoubleAnimation
         {
             From = 0,
             To = 1,
             Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5),
             FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
         };

         fade.Completed += delegate
         {
             element.Opacity = 1;
             element.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
             Debug.WriteLine(QuestionNumber + " Visibility : " + Visibility + " | opacity : " + Opacity);
         };

         Storyboard.SetTarget(fade, element);
         Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fade, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));

         var sb = new Storyboard();
         sb.Children.Add(fade);

         sb.Begin();
 }
```

For debugging I write the question number, `Visibility` and `Opacity` when the animation is complete. Here's and example of the log when I set the date of the first question to a date less than a year from today:

```
15.1 Visibility : Visible | opacity : 1
15.1 Visibility : Visible | opacity : 1
15.2 Visibility : Visible | opacity : 1
15.2 Visibility : Visible | opacity : 1
15.5 Visibility : Visible | opacity : 1
15.5 Visibility : Visible | opacity : 1
15.3 Visibility : Visible | opacity : 1
```

Notice that `15.3` has `Visibility : Visible | opacity : 1`, but it does not show up in the program, and inspecting with Snoop tells me that it has `Visibility = Collapsed` and  `Opacity = 0`.

All other questions fade in and out as expected.

Any ideas?

---

**Update**

I added a handler to `IsVisibleChanged += OnVisibleChanged;`

```
private void OnVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var q = sender as QuestionBase;
    if(q.QuestionNumber == "15.3")
        Debug.WriteLine(q.QuestionNumber +
        " VISIBILITY CHANGED TO " +
        e.NewValue +
        " | Property :" + e.Property);
}
```

Im getting this when its hidden on init :

```
15.3 VISIBILITY CHANGED TO False| Property :IsVisible
15.3 Faded Out
```

When setting the date I get:

```
15.3 Areq changed to : True // from OnAnswerRequiredChanged
15.3 Visibility : Visible | opacity : 1 // from FadeIn
```

But `OnVisibleChanged` is not fired! 
I changed the `debug.WriteLine` in `FadeIn` to be positive that I'm writing the vlues of `element`.

So how am I getting `15.3 Visibility : Visible` without raising `IsVisibleChanged`.

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint into your Dependency property setter and track its changes? If snoop shows the value to be Collapsed then the value of your bound property much have changed somewhere down the line just before the xaml was rendered

Comment: Note that your debug output does not show `element.Visibility` and `element.Opacity`, but instead the values of the `Visibility` and `Opacity` properties of the instance of the class that owns the `FadeIn` method.

Comment: @Clemens, thanks. But they should be the same. I'm calling it with `this`.

Comment: @Jinish, I'll try throwing some breakpoints in there. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

try expand Mainwindow.xaml's frame  **MinHeight="500" MinWidth="700"**
if your element was outside of frame that element not shown